# Why isn't my php code triggered on form submit?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'll explain my code and then proceed to the problem after the code snippets:

I have a form called "functions_questions." When it gets submitted, the following code either increases or decreases a column (titled "score") in my sql database (titled "answers") depending the current score.

```
<?php  
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['functions_question'])){

    $res = $db->query("SELECT score FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
    $data = $res->fetch_array();

    if($data['score']<2)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET score = score+1 WHERE id=$id");

    if($data['score']>1)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET score = score-1 WHERE id=$id");

  }

?>
```

I also have the following AJAX code which automatically changes the text in a div (id = "ajaxtest") when the form is submitted. Of course, this does so without refreshing the page, as it uses AJAX.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#questionform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) { 

ajaxtest.innerHTML = '"<?php echo $data['score']; ?>"';

            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Lastly, I have the following bit of code, which shows the value in the column titled "score" in the database titled "answers."

```
<?php
$resss = $db->query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
$data = $resss->fetch_array();
var_dump($data['score']);
?>
```

When I submit my form, I can see as an admin in the database that the score has updated. The AJAX code changes the div (ajaxtest) to $data['score'], but it displays the former score prior to the update, rather than the newly updated score. How can I modify this so that ajaxtest displays the updated score rather than the non-updated score?

Comment: Is the form itself named `functions_questions`? Or is that actually the name of an input/button/submit/other form field in your form?

Comment: That's the name of the form.

Comment: In HTML, the form itself is not a form element; it doesn't have a value, and is not submitted. You need to test based on an actual form element that *is* submitted.

Comment: The value of `<?php echo $data['score']; ?>` is fixed as of page load - PHP renders the page, including javascript, before sending it. If you want to use data returned from your PHP script you need to change your success callback to do something like `ajaxtest.innerHTML = data.score;`

Comment: Hm, when I change it to `ajaxtest.innerHTML = 'data.score';` the div just changes to "data.score."

Comment: Also, beware of `$(this).serialize()` inside `$.ajax()`, you most probably want `$(this).serializeObject()`. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is because the statement `ajaxtest.innerHTML = '"<?php echo $data['score']; ?>"';` is evaluated as soon as the file is served, thus transforming to `ajaxtest.innerHTML = <score when file was served>';`.

If you'd like to show the new value then you'd have either to retrieve it with another asynchronous request (commonly referred as AJAX call) or return the value in the code reponsible for managing the call and using it through the data argument:

**EDIT**

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#questionform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) { 
                ajaxtest.innerHTML = data;
            },
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['functions_question'])){

        $res = $db->query("SELECT score FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
        $data = $res->fetch_array();

        if($data['score'] < 2)
            $db->query("UPDATE answers SET score = score+1 WHERE id=$id");

        if($data['score'] > 1)
            $db->query("UPDATE answers SET score = score-1 WHERE id=$id");
        $res = $db->query("SELECT score FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
        $data = $res->fetch_array();

        echo $data['score'];
    }
```

It goes like this:

1. File is served and all PHP statements in it are evaluated, a response is sent to client
2. AJAX request to server
3. Server processes request
4. AJAX receives response (data)
5. You use response data

You can inspect the result of AJAX requests in Chrome by enabling the developer tools (generally ctrl+shift+i) and in the 'network' tab enable XHR.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I'm a bit confused as to how to apply that to my AJAX code (the second block of code in my post). I thought it was already set up in the JS format that you posted above. Should I replace `ajaxtest.innerHTML = '"<?php echo $data['score']; ?>"';` with the PHP code you wrote there? Sorry to seem so dense, but I'm a complete novice.

Comment: As per why repeating the query solves the problem is because you are then retrieving the new value from the database and populating $data with it.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you! Hopefully this is my last question: how does  `ajaxtest.innerHTML = data;` 'know' which data to reference? In other words, what part of the code links that PHP to the JS?

Comment: When I made those changes and submitted the form, it ended replaced that div with an entire copy of my web page. (I know you can't see the full code, but I'm guessing 'data' is currently referring to a lot more than just that PHP code.) Therefore, I suppose a more productive question than the one I asked above would be: is there a way to specify that I want 'data' to specifically refer to that bit of PHP code?

Comment: data refers to everything in the response. You could trying adding a `die();` statement after the `echo $data['score'];` one. That'd ensure that the response only contains the value of the score.

Furthermore, to access `data` inside JS as an object with properties you would have to return a response from PHP in some format like JSON. However, as you seem to be just starting your journey in PHP coding I guess this approach is good for now. However, it has several disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your PHP code with following :-

```
<?php  
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['functions_question'])){

        $res = $db->query("SELECT score FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
        $data = $res->fetch_array();

        if($data['score']<2)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET score = score+1 WHERE id=$id");

        if($data['score']>1)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET score = score-1 WHERE id=$id");

        $res = $db->query("SELECT score FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
        $data = $res->fetch_array();

    }

?>
```

It may help you.

I just get score after the update the new record.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Why might repeating `$res = $db->query("SELECT score FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
        $data = $res->fetch_array();` at the end of the code help resolve the issue?

Comment: because You get value before then you got 1 and after you update these value so now Its 2, But you are displaying the value that are old one before the update query.